# Variable undefined in Gatling script

Tags: gatling

Gatling Newbie here. I am trying to check the html of my page using the below documented css selector. The css item is present on the page (verified with postman) but Gatling is not finding it. I receive a variable undefined error on compile. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class LoggingIn extends Simulation {

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL("https://test.spidastudio.com")
        .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.js""", """.*\.css""", """.*\.gif""", """.*\.jpeg""", """.*\.jpg""", """.*\.ico""", """.*\.woff""", """.*\.(t|o)tf""", """.*\.png"""), WhiteList())

    val headers_0 = Map(
        "User-Agent"-> "Gatling",
        "Accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding" -> "gzip, deflate",
        "Cache-Control" -> "max-age=0",
        "Origin" -> "https://test.spidastudio.com",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests" -> "1")

    val headers_1 = Map("User-Agent"-> "Gatling","X-Requested-With" -> "XMLHttpRequest")

    val uri1 = "https://test.spidastudio.com"



    val scn = scenario("LoggingIn")
        .exec(http("REQUEST A")
            .post("/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.spidastudio.com%2Fprojectmanager%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check")

            //Defining variable LTValue
            .check(css("input[name=lt]", "value").saveAs("LTValue"))
        )
        .exec(http("request_0")
            .post("/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.spidastudio.com%2Fprojectmanager%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check")

            .headers(headers_0) 
            .formParam("username", "xxxxxxx.com")
            .formParam("password", "xxxxxxxx")
            //Calling variable
            .formParam("lt", "${LTValue}")
```

Comment: "I receive a variable undefined error on compile" ... the code does not compile? "The css item is present on the page" - Than this does not matter - or? What about the compile error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by removing this line from your code?

```
.inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.js""", """.*\.css""", """.*\.gif""", """.*\.jpeg""", """.*\.jpg""", """.*\.ico""", """.*\.woff""", """.*\.(t|o)tf""", """.*\.png"""), WhiteList())
```

or remove *.css""" ? Works?